# Stop music if stopButton pressed

Tags: android, audio

I'm creating an audio player and can't resolve one issue. I have two buttons - start and stop, and one progress bar. When I'm changing progress bar I stop the music in the onStartTrackingTouch method of setOnSeekBarChangeListener to have smooth changing and resume the music in onStopTrackingTouch when changing is stopped. But if the StopButton is pressed and if changing is in progress after I stop changing the music starts to play again. I want to resume music after stop changing only if the StopButton wasn't pressed before changing. How to fix it?

```
playProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean fromUser){
                if(fromUser){
                    mPlayer.seekTo(i);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
                mPlayer.pause();
        }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
                mPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    //======================================================
}

public void startAudio(View view) {
         mPlayer.start();
}

public void pauseAudio(View view) {
        mPlayer.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use always simple flag . Flag can be any of variable type. In this case is normal to be Boolean in other ways usually goes Int .

```
// Create flag 
var STOP_BTN_IS_PRESSED = false;

playProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean fromUser){
                if(fromUser){
                    mPlayer.seekTo(i);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
                mPlayer.pause();
        }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
                  if ( STOP_BTN_IS_PRESSED == false) {
                        mPlayer.start();
                  }
        }
    });

    //======================================================
}

public void startAudio(View view) {

         STOP_BTN_IS_PRESSED = false;

         mPlayer.start();
}

public void pauseAudio(View view) {

         STOP_BTN_IS_PRESSED = true;

        mPlayer.pause();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thanks! I tried a flag but got confused with it and failed :)

Comment: Please click positive make my day  ;)

Comment: I'd do it with pleasure but my rating is under 15 so I can't do that :(

Comment: Where is it? Haven't any green color on the screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   under negative button , sorry ist green it is gray when you click on it , color will be green . Go to some of green marked Q/A and then will be clear situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
playProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int i, boolean fromUser){

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
             mPlayer.pause();
        }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
                mPlayer.seekTo(seekbar.getProgress());
                mPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    //======================================================
}
```

Comment: It's what I want but if I hold the thumb of progressBar and changing it while music is playing the music jerked.

Comment: stop music when you touch/changing the progress and Resume when progress change completed